# Show rows based on id

Tags: jquery

I have a table structure where the rows comes from a database like this:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
...
    <tr>
     <td>Dataset1 <button id="@(item.Id)">Show more</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="@(item.Id)">
     <td>Data from Dataset1</td>  
    </tr>
```

So my table looks like this for example

```html
<tr>
  <td>Dataset1 <button id="1">Show more</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="1">
  <td>Data from Dataset1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Dataset4 <button id="4">Show more</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="4">
  <td>Data from Dataset4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Dataset5 <button id="5">Show more</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="5">
  <td>Data from Dataset5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Dataset6 <button id="6">Show more</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="6">
  <td>Data from Dataset6</td>
</tr>
```

Now I would like to show or hide the different lines with the corresponding button with jquery.
But everything I've tried so far does not work.
Is there even the possibility to pass an id?

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("id").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `id` values **must** be unique in the document. You can't have the same `id` on both a `tr` and a `button`.

Comment: Also `$('id')` is not valid.  It needs to be either `('#id')` for a literal or `$('#'+ id)` if id is a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` values **must** be unique in the document. You can't have the same `id` on both a `tr` and a `button`.

The solution is: Don't use `id` at all. Put a class on your buttons and use traversal to find the row to toggle. I'd probably also use a delegated handler on the table rather than per button.

```js
$("#the-table").on("click", ".show-more", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<table id="the-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Dataset1 <button class="show-more">Show more</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>Data from Dataset1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dataset4 <button class="show-more">Show more</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>Data from Dataset4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dataset5 <button class="show-more">Show more</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>Data from Dataset5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dataset6 <button class="show-more">Show more</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>Data from Dataset6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(You might also use a class for hiding/showing and `toggleClass` rather than `toggle`.)

Comment: Now I see
Dataset 1 (Button)
Dataset 4 (Button)
Dataset 5 (Button)
Dataset 6 (Button)

But pressing the button brings nothing.

Comment: @Paul_412 - I'm not sure what you mean. The above clearly toggles the next row, see the live example.

Comment: I´ve seen the live example. This is exactly what i want. In my environment it does not yet work. I am using asp.net and have packed the script in the _Layout.cshtml. I hope to find the mistake on my side.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works.
Can you explain me also the solution with class for hiding/showing?

Comment: @Paul_412 - Basically you start out with a class on the rows instead of `style` where the class is defined in CSS as `.the-class { display: none; }` and then use `.toggleClass("the-class")` rather than `.toggle()`. One thing that does for you is let you define transitions in CSS if you like (for insatnce, to make the row slide down or slide up rather than just appearing/disappearing). More: [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)